# How to convert base64 to a TIFF image or a PNG image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a base64 encoded string of a TIFF image type and I want to convert it into a PNG image using python. I saw a package pillow which can manipulate a tiff file but how to proceed with a given "base64 of TIFF"?

Comment: you have  `base64.b64encode()` and `base64.b64decode()`. After decoding you may save it as TIFF using standard `open(filename, 'wb').write(data)` without `pillow`

Comment: I tried this approach, but the saved image is damaged & when I open the same base64 in google chrome it automatically downloads the perfect file in .tiff format.

Comment: if you tried the show code in question. You can also add link to this data so we can test code.

Comment: the most common mistake people make is saving in text mode but it has to be bytes mode `'wb'`

Comment: Damn, I figured out the mistake. I had the mime type of the image attached in the base64 variable string. Now, it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base64` to `tiff`:

```
import base64

text_base64 = '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'

bytes_base64 = text_base64.encode()
data = base64.b64decode(bytes_base64)
open('image.tiff', 'wb').write(data)
```

`tiff` to `base64` and `html`:

```
import base64

data = open('image.tiff', 'rb').read()
bytes_base64 = base64.b64encode(data)
text_base64 = bytes_base64.decode()

print(text_base64)

html = '<img src="data:image/tiff;base64,' + text_base64 + '">'
open('output-tiff.html', 'w').write(html)
```

Probably most browsers can't display tiff so file .html may display broken image. You would have to save it from page to file and then you can see tiff.

---

This is image used in examples but here in `png` format:

[image: face.tiff]

---

**EDIT:** example with the same image but in `png` format. This html will display image in every browser.

```
# base64 to png

import base64

text_base64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAAAAACoWZBhAAAAMklEQVR4nEXNwQkAMBACwfFI/y2bxwXia8FFUwF1pCCNJTIIwaD04ctsKRyaldI/9i8u1iwOE6FA880AAAAASUVORK5CYII='

bytes_base64 = text_base64.encode()
data = base64.b64decode(bytes_base64)
open('image.png', 'wb').write(data)

# png to base64 and html

import base64

data = open('image.png', 'rb').read()
bytes_base64 = base64.b64encode(data)
text_base64 = bytes_base64.decode()

print(text_base64)

html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + text_base64 + '">'
open('output-png.html', 'w').write(html)
```

Comment: Yes, .tiff is mostly supported in Microsoft Edge, Chrome or Mozilla shows a broken link. I was earlier decoding with "data:image/tiff;base64" present with the encoded string and hence, the broken image. Thank you for your efforts. :)

Comment: I added example with `png`

Comment: few days ago I created base64 with png for answer to other question on SO.

Comment: Using the PIL you can directly read the image and save it in any format needed. or by using a standard f.write with the mimetype and base64.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it for PNG in Python Wand, which is based upon Imagemagick.

```
#!/bin/python3.7

from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='inline:data:image/png;base64,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') as img:
    img.save(filename='noseguy_b64.png')
```

[image]